# Permalink to custom query parameter result

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

Currently, if you edit a query (which has parameters), and then run it, the SEDE tool allows you to click a "permalink":

[image]

In the example above, the permalink is: [`https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/361538/example-permalink?PTID=1`](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/361538/example-permalink?PTID=1)

Note how the PTID parameter is included as part of the permalink.

That's great, but, if you change the PTID value, and rerun the query, there is no place to save the permalink away:

[image]

---

Now, before you dismiss this as being a trivial requirement, I have some queries where the parameters are really quite complicated, like.... this monster:

[`https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/327233/site-relative-stats?SiteName=StackExchange.CodeReview&Query=select+count(%2A)+from+%5Bsite%5D..Badges+where+name+%3D+%27Constituent%27#resultSets`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/327233/site-relative-stats?SiteName=StackExchange.CodeReview&Query=select+count(%2A)+from+%5Bsite%5D..Badges+where+name+%3D+%27Constituent%27#resultSets)

If/when I change a custom query in that report, it would be great to be able to permalink the effect.

Comment: FWIW, I agree it's not trivial, I've been meaning to add it.