# Provide a permalink to a query with parameters

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, permalink

I've noticed that sometimes I get a "permalink" for a query that includes the parameters I gave. This is very inconsistent, and I failed to find out when it's provided and when it isn't.

So I have to construct the necessary URL by hand if I need to share the query results. I don't even know the syntax for this unless I accidentally came across a permalink with parameters in the past. ([I did](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace/370103#370103), and already forgot the syntax.)

So, I propose to either

- Always provide a permalink to a query, complete with parameters, that would give the same result that you've got, or
- Change the active page URL when I change the parameters so that I can copy it instead (I'll probably have to chop off `#resultSets` though, so this look inferior at first glance).

Comment: fork the query (or make sure you make an edit to one of your own queries) and run it. That will give you the permalink.

Comment: @rene why should I need to fork a query to share the result of its run? Not to mention that would reference the forked query, not the original one.

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: @rene It makes a mess of query history and things like stars. Plus it's completely counterintuitive.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266039/permalink-to-custom-query-parameter-result and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296593/cannot-get-parameterized-permalinks-to-sede-queries-i-own

Comment: Great idea. Was looking to do the same.